Tomcat 9 can still not find classes which are symlinked (allowlinking="true")
Hello we use Caucho Resin which apparently died so switching to Tomcat 9 for now until we can move past Java 8.
We use Ubuntu 20.04.
I have it sorta working except for one thing killing me - still can't get symlinks to work in paths, especially loading classes.  I have been doing mount --bind as a workaround but now I really need to find a solution.
Here is what I have tried:
try 1:
context.xml:
<Context>
  <Resources allowLinking="true" />
  <Resources cacheMaxSize="51200" />
 ...

try 2:
server.xml:
<Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="myXapp">
      <Resources allowLinking="true" />
      <Resources cacheMaxSize="51200" />
</Context>

<Context path="/ROOT" docBase="ROOT"/>

Try 2 doesn't resolve symlink either, but at least now I can access my application at "/".
I also tried using files in catalina/localhost with no better outcome and path is ignore.
This doesn't make any difference.  When I hit the .jsp file I get no errors in the log only the failure to compile because a variable "cannot be resolved to a type". So the class was just silently ignored.
If I delete the symlink and replace with a mount --bind, it works as expected and the JSP is executed.
Every single Google search always takes me back to "allowlinking=true", and I follow the solutions but it doesn't work for me.
Edit for clarification: We are not trying to deploy a WAR file, we just added an app in the webapps folder and have been trying to symlink parts of that app.
Progress Edit: We eventually did the mount --bind for classes, so got past that although not ideal.  However the symlinks on jsp pages and folders really are required and we are stuck on that one. It still silently ignores anything symlinked in the application folder.

After a lot of grief I found the issue by posting to the Tomcat users board.  The solution is just to remove everything I had tried, then put my application in ROOT in webapps then create /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/META-INF/context.xml and put:
<Context>
   <Resources allowLinking="true" cacheMaxSize="51200" />
</Context>

